# Spring Cloud message serialisation problem with Kafka running in docker container

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-cloud, avro, confluent-schema-registry

I'm trying to write a test for my Spring Cloud service while it runs against Kafka and Schema Registry which run inside Docker containers.

Kafka and Schema Registry communicate with each other via a docker network, and have ports that are exposed on the host. The service I am testing is running on the host - it is able to communicate with both the docker kafka broker and docker schema registry. I am starting it up from a JUnit test which is annotated as shown below.

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = TestSupportBinderAutoConfiguration.class)
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
public class MyTest {
    ...
}
```

My service spins up and is able to write a message to the Kafka broker running inside the Docker container, however when my service is started using the various Spring / JUnit test annotations, there appears to be something different about the way the message it writes is serialized compared to when my service runs in 'production mode' (i.e. if I run it using using `java -jar com.xyz.MyService`).

The message needs to be written in Avro format, so I've configured the binder in application.yml as

```
my-topic:
   destination: my-topic
   contentType: application/*+avro
   producer:
      useNativeEncoding: true
```

When attempting to consume the message that my service has written, `AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer` blows up, complaining that it was unable to marshal it into a completely unrelated Avro type:

```
{"logger_name":"org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.LogAndFailExceptionHandler","message":"Exception caught during Deserialization, taskId: 0_0, topic: my-topic, partition: 0, offset: 1","stack_trace":"org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Could not find class com.xyz.SomeOtherMessageType specified in writer's schema whilst finding reader's schema for a SpecificRecord.
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.getSpecificReaderSchema(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:265)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.getReaderSchema(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:247)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.getDatumReader(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:194)
...
```

This does not happen if my service runs in 'production mode'.

I think therefore that some setting is being applied to my service when I spin it up in 'test mode', which changes the way messages are encoded or serialized.

Can anyone suggest some things I can try to resolve this?

**Update 1**

So, it turns out that the messages looks pretty much identical when they are written to the topic and then read back (UUIDs are random for each test run):

Written to topic by service running in 'test mode':

```
Address  0 1 2 3  4 5 6 7  8 9 A B  C D E F  0123456789ABCDEF
------- -------- -------- -------- --------  ----------------
000000: 00000000 01483335 63616366 62642D30  .....H35cacfbd-0
000010: 3165642D 34653564 2D613936 652D6665  1ed-4e5d-a96e-fe
000020: 30626339 65313033 34664832 35313436  0bc9e1034fH25146
000030: 6237392D 66643334 2D346430 322D6261  b79-fd34-4d02-ba
000040: 37362D36 61396535 62623861 31343448  76-6a9e5bb8a144H
000050: 30653364 30326536 2D383732 372D3466  0e3d02e6-8727-4f
000060: 64312D38 3730662D 33646633 35353166  d1-870f-3df3551f
000070: 37343861 084D7220 54064D72 730A4A69  748a.Mr T.Mrs.Ji
000080: 6D6D790A 57686974 6514536E 6F772068  mmy.White.Snow h
000090: 6F757365 00000012 4C697665 72706F6F  ouse....Liverpoo
0000A0: 6C0C4C4C 32335252 0E456E67 6C616E64  l.XXXXXX.England
0000B0: 16303735 31323334 35363738 021E4D72  .XXXXXXXXXXX..Mr
0000C0: 20542773 20427573 696E6573 73483737   T's BusinessH77
0000D0: 32383064 36352D36 3633362D 34376565  280d65-6636-47ee
0000E0: 2D393864 302D6361 36646531 32373838  -98d0-ca6de12788
0000F0: 63610000                             ca..
```

Written to topic by service running in 'production mode':

```
Address  0 1 2 3  4 5 6 7  8 9 A B  C D E F  0123456789ABCDEF
------- -------- -------- -------- --------  ----------------
000000: 00000000 57483433 64343264 61372D30  ....WH43d42da7-0
000010: 6533392D 34646665 2D383966 362D6531  e39-4dfe-89f6-e1
000020: 37363036 34383730 61344833 38663864  76064870a4H38f8d
000030: 3561342D 65386532 2D346134 372D6235  5a4-e8e2-4a47-b5
000040: 30662D37 31623435 36653837 33393348  0f-71b456e87393H
000050: 63666463 33653964 2D303362 612D3464  cfdc3e9d-03ba-4d
000060: 62372D62 3034622D 31393137 37323634  b7-b04b-19177264
000070: 36623665 084D7220 54064D72 730A4A69  6b6e.Mr T.Mrs.Ji
000080: 6D6D790A 57686974 6514536E 6F772068  mmy.White.Snow h
000090: 6F757365 00000012 4C697665 72706F6F  ouse....Liverpoo
0000A0: 6C0C4C4C 32335252 0E456E67 6C616E64  l.XXXXXX.England
0000B0: 16303735 31323334 35363738 021E4D72  .XXXXXXXXXXX..Mr
0000C0: 20542773 20427573 696E6573 73486161   T's BusinessHaa
0000D0: 35326636 34662D36 6131642D 34393030  52f64f-6a1d-4900
0000E0: 2D616537 612D3432 33326333 65613938  -ae7a-4232c3ea98
0000F0: 38330000                             83..
```

Comment: So this "unrelated type" exists nowhere on your classpath and you've not set that type as the specific type being consumed, and that type is not part of the registered schema ? In other words, why would the error include it, then? Also is "production mode" using a different registry?

Comment: I should elaborate -- I have spun up a number of dockerised services which are involved in a particular flow. The spring cloud service in question (running on the host) sits in the middle of that flow. The upstream service registers a bunch of types in the schema registry. The downstream service is where I see an error, complaining that it cannot deserialize the message that my spring cloud service has produced. The downstream service doesn't have the class mentioned in the error message on its classpath. All services are using the same schema registry.

Comment: And you are trying to use `specific` reader during deserialization, as compared to using `GenericRecord`? If so, then the writer's classes must be on the consumer's classpath. Outside of this, your local tests should be isolated from external services

Comment: Yep, I'm using a `SpecificRecord` reader. The unrelated type that is identified by the downstream service is written to a different topic (and, in fact, no messages of that type are written anywhere during the test). The type of the message that is written to the topic is on the classpath of both the 'locally running' service and the downstream service. The random type that the downstream service tries to deserialize the message to is different for each execution of the same test - like the first n bytes of the message usually used to identify the schema are not being used for that at all.

Comment: Last I checked, you cannot bypass the KafkaAvroDeserializer ID byte check. But still unclear why any class that isn't being produced would be mentioned unless some producer process sent this record to the topic you're consuming, and you just don't know about it.

Comment: Ah, sorry - what I meant, but articulated poorly, is that perhaps the first n bytes of the message that is serialized by the locally running service do not indicate the schema registry identifier because the wrong encoding has been used to write the message to the topic (for some reason) but when the downstream service deserializes the message, it reads the first n bytes and assumes that they identify an avro type in the schema registry, which is why the downstream service is trying to deserialize it to a seemingly random type each time

Answer (score 2):

[Testcontainers Kafka module](https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/kafka/) runs a single node Kafka installation. It doesn't spin up a Schema Registry. Which I suspect might be a problem for Avro serialization.

You can add it manually to the tests. Testcontainers allows to run any Docker image programmatically with a simple API call:

```
var schemaRegistry = new GenericContainer(DockerImageName.parse("confluentcp/cp-schema-registry:version"));
```

I don't know for certain, but you probably need to connect Kafka and the schema registry, which you can do with the `Network`, see the [Advanced networking](https://www.testcontainers.org/features/networking/#advanced-networking) chapter in the docs.

Unfortunately, I don't have a good example to refer to.

You can also look at something like this: https://github.com/kreuzwerker/kafka-consumer-testing.

They mock schema registry url so there's no separate schema registry container.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am also spinning up the Schema Registry in a separate container. Schema Registry and Kafka are able to communicate with each other on a docker network. I'll update my question to make that clearer